# task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I'm compiling my project for distribution and I've gotten an error.

Here's the error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
 > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command      'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I've gone in and gotten the stacktrace-* Try:
Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.execution.TaskSelectionException: Task 'compileDebug' is ambiguous in root project 'Inspirerr_Final'. Candidates are: 'compileDebugAidl', 'compileDebugAndroidTestAidl', 'compileDebugAndroidTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugAndroidTestNdk', 'compileDebugAndroidTestRenderscript', 'compileDebugAndroidTestSources', 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugNdk', 'compileDebugRenderscript', 'compileDebugSources', 'compileDebugUnitTestJavaWithJavac', 'compileDebugUnitTestSources'.
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:101)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskSelector.getSelection(TaskSelector.java:76)
    at org.gradle.execution.commandline.CommandLineTaskParser.parseTasks(CommandLineTaskParser.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$100(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.select(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:142)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)


BUILD FAILED
```

And my gradle file

```
:apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

buildscript {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
         }

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7

}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-     types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}

}
```

Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe.there are such code in your BuildConfig,

```
// Fields from build type: debug
public static final boolean ENABLE_DEVELOP_MODE = true;
```

And you use it in some place.
When you build release, it will dismiss and build failed.